# Routes grouped does not work in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hey guys okay? I have a problem in pooled routes laravel 5. When I access 'localhost/painel' displays a 404 error (see the code below):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'painel', 'namespace' => 'Backend'], function(){

    // Login Routes
    Route::get('/', 'LoginController@getLogin');
});
```

Already I access 'localhost/painel/teste' with the following code works:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'painel', 'namespace' => 'Backend'], function(){

    // Login Routes
    Route::get('/teste', 'LoginController@getLogin');
});
```

Only I need that control becomes accessible through the route 'localhost/painel'. What am I doing wrong?

thank you!!!

Comment: Your route get may be looking for an ending backslash, I would replace it with a `{all}` and make sure it's your last route in the group to catch anything that was not already caught by a previous route.

Comment: do you confirm that, `LoginController` under `Backend` namespace?